# Trying to print multiple entries from the same variable

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

I'm curious if there's a way I can loop multiple entries of the same string variable? Basically I'm wanting to print multiple entries of the players name into a For Loop, however I'm having a brainfart and I'm stumped on how I can extend off the simple piece of code I've written so far with my while-loop.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    string choice = "y";
    string player_name = "";

    while (choice == "y")
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the players name: ");
        player_name = Console.ReadLine();


        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another player? y/n");
        choice = Console.ReadLine();

    }
    Console.WriteLine(player_name);

    Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: putting the WriteLine(player_name) within the while loop doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Put the names in a list, then loop through the list:

```
List<string> player_names = new List<string>();

do {

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the players name: ");
    player_name = Console.ReadLine();
    player_names.Add(player_name);

    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to enter another player? y/n");
} while (Console.ReadLine() == "y");

foreach (string name in player_names) {
  Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: List! I haven't worked with that one yet, but this exactly what I need it to do. Thanks for your quick response.